# Docker Upgrade without loosing data

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Guy, I have the following yaml file of a docker
root@Raspberrypi4:/home/pi/zwavejs2mqtt# more docker-compose.yaml

```
services:
  zwavejs2mqtt:
    container_name: zwavejs2mqtt
    image: zwavejs/zwavejs2mqtt:latest
    restart: always
    tty: true
    stop_signal: SIGINT
    environment:
      - SESSION_SECRET=mysupersecretkey
      - ZWAVEJS_EXTERNAL_CONFIG=/usr/src/app/store/.config-db
      # Uncomment if you want logs time and dates to match your timezone instead of UTC
      # Available at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
      #- TZ=America/New_York
      - TZ=Asia/Nicosia
    networks:
      - zwave
    devices:
      # Do not use /dev/ttyUSBX serial devices, as those mappings can change over time.
      # Instead, use the /dev/serial/by-id/X serial device for your Z-Wave stick.
      - '/dev/zwave:/dev/zwave'
    volumes:
      - zwave-config:/usr/src/app/store
    ports:
      - '8091:8091' # port for web interface
      - '3000:3000' # port for Z-Wave JS websocket server
networks:
  zwave:
volumes:
  zwave-config:
    name: zwave-config
```

I am starting the docker issuing the command "docker-compose up --detach".
How can I perform a docker upgrade without loosing any data which reside inside the docker?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Data should be stored in volumes, allowing you to `docker-compose pull` and `docker-compose up -d` to pull new images and restart the service using those new images.

If data is not stored in volumes, it will be visible in the output of `docker diff` and you can try extracting that data with `docker cp`.

For more details on those commands, see the documentation at:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/diff/
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

Comment: This is no clear here what you are suggesting here. So, If i run a docker-compose pull this will make the upgrade inside the container preserving the changes inside the container? The diff command returned,  So, these files were created/modified after the container creation. If the diff does not "reset" the container why should i use the cp command?
C /root
A /root/.ash_history
C /usr
C /usr/src
C /usr/src/app
C /usr/src/app/node_modules
C /usr/src/app/node_modules/zwave-js
A /usr/src/app/node_modules/zwave-js/fingerprint.txt

Comment: A `docker-compose up -d` will replace the container if the image is changed from the pull. The new container will not have any filesystem changes shown in the diff. You should save them if you don't want to lose them, and use a volume to capture them in the future. Some changes are not important to keep, which ones you need depends on the app and I'm not familiar with zwave.